# ASP Classic 500 Error, ASP_CLIENT_DISCONNECTED followed by ASP_LOG_ERROR

Tags: http, asp-classic

I've got a problem that for a website I'm administering, users are getting a 500 error. It happens across the site in a number of random places, like performing an Ajax query, navigating from page to page, etc. In the IIS error request log, what I'm seeing is two errors, back-to-back: ASP_CLIENT_DISCONNECTED and ASP_LOG_ERROR. Users are reporting problems usually happen when they're navigating from page to page. The 500 error appears and it just sits there. If they get the error, they usually refresh and it goes away.

The chain of calls right before the error look like the following.

```
ISAPI_START

CALL_ISAPI_EXTENSION

ASP_START_REQUEST

ASP_NEW_SESSION_CREATED

ASP_QUEUE_REQUEST

ASP_DEQUEUE_REQUEST

ASP_CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
    Error  17:46:48.254 

ASP_LOG_ERROR
    Error LineNumber="", ErrorCode="ASP 0147", Description="500 Server Error" 17:46:48.254 

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
    ModuleName="IsapiModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="500", HttpReason="Server Error", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

EDIT 0: I think that the key may lie in that ASP_NEW_SESSION_CREATED line. I don't have any hard evidence to support that, just a gut feeling.

A few more details about my environment, I'm using an Application Pool that is in Classic Mode using the .NET Framework v2.0.5.2707. As part of the web site, I have two web applications that use a .NET 4.0 Application Pool in Integrated mode. The web applications aren't being used at all so I don't think they come into play.

Any suggestions about how to approach this one are greatly appreciated.

mj

Comment: Have you seen this .. http://forums.iis.net/p/1155791/2001665.aspx#2001665

Comment: Thanks for the find, but yes, I did see that one. Our user aren't refreshing or closing anything though on any complicated pages w/ outstanding Ajax requests. Just simple navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer. There was an Ajax request that was timing out on the server and causing the problem. Some of the other calls were indeed due to user impatience.